# DirectX Windows 8.1 fstream won't load file

Tags: c++11, directx-11

I'm building a Windows 8.1 DirectX app and trying to load in an external to store level data.

The relevant code currently is (this method is called in the AssetHandler constructor):

```
void AssetHandler::LoadLevelsData()
{ 
  unsigned int i = 0;
  std::string lineData;

  this->currentFile.open("Assets/reg.txt");
  //Below statement here purely to check if the blasted thing is opening
  if (this->currentFile.is_open())
  {

    i++;
  }
  while (std::getline(this->currentFile, lineData))
  {
    levels[i] = lineData;
    i++;
  }
  currentFile.close();
}
```

The problem that i'm having is that the file does not appear to be opening. I have tried:

- Using a full path
- Opening the file in the initialisation list
- A breakpoint shows that it is jumping over the if and while

I found some information saying that DirectX has constraints on working with external files but it did not specify exactly what these were.

Comment: This question does not seem to be related to DirectX.

Comment: I just didn't want to rule anything out. I was under the impression that this issue may be specific to developing a DirectX app.

Answer (score 1):

The Item Type was set to 'Does not participate in build'. Setting this value to 'Text' solved the problem.

Comment: That means the error you got was that it wasn't present.  You should be able to call ``errno`` or ``GetLastError()`` when the ``is_open`` returns false to find out what happened.